# Lazy-Load SO Posts

Tags: feature-request, performance

When browsing [an entertaining post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939130/8804293) on SO, I noticed the scrollbar was tiny... Meaning that the page was very long.

I threw the source code in a character counter and got `313886` characters. That's quite a bit.

I didn't read past a post or two, and I feel that most people don't read all the way down to the bottom of a thread. So, **I propose lazy loading posts instead of serving all of them up on load** to reduce latency on both the client and server.

After scrolling down past a few posts, a few more would load (with fetch or something), and this would continue with scroll if the user stays on the page. This would avoid transferring data that is never read.

Comment: This makes `Ctrl`+`F` search on a page a bit harder. Is your feature request mainly about reducing bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, and because I think it is a waste to send data that is not seen/used, but you make a good point about searching.

Comment: *"I feel that most people don't..."*  Based on what evidence? More current answers on older posts sometimes have more modern approaches that weren't available at the time the original post and answers were created

Comment: There is already several forms of "lazy load", like only 20 answers shown at a time, or not all comments on Qs and As shown unless asked for. And I'm not fond of lazy loading the way you want, because that small page just keeps growing and growing (a 5 minute read turns into 30), and sometimes stuff starts to move around.

Comment: "I propose lazy loading posts instead of serving all of them up on load to reduce latency on both the client and server" - I would assume SO can accept funding for such alternative implementation... Note that since search engine traffic is critical for SO I doubt they have an option to abandon server side rendering - so basically you are asking for 2 rendering implementations based on a totally questionable claim that "pages using JavaScript and multiple calls to servers are consistently faster on all devices than cacheable HTML+CSS only rendering".

Comment: Wait, you detected latency when loading that page? How much was it? And how much  was it on a "small" page?

Comment: I find lazy loading, or should I say trickle loading, a pretty ugly user experience to be honest. Hard to get right on mobile devices especially, I know some sites where I have to basically scroll up and down up and down to get the site to trigger the next trickle load and the fact that things appear out of nowhere tends to trigger me to tap something I didn't want to tap. I'd be all for a way to set the maximum number of answers in a page though, so you personally can set it to 2 and I can leave it at 20.

Answer (score 5):

> I propose lazy loading posts instead of serving all of them up on load to reduce latency on both the client and server.

That is an interesting request, specially because I'm under the impression load times for Stack Overflow pages is pretty good if not excellent, specially at the server side. You might experience lag if your internet connection is slow but you need to make serious efforts to compensate for lack of band-width at a client.

Let's analyze what we're talking about. I suggest reading [How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl) because I'm using that approach to get some hard numbers on performance and it is appreciated if others can replicate my data.

For [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) the curl stats I get are:

```
    time_namelookup:  0,031464s
       time_connect:  0,041339s
    time_appconnect:  0,081889s
   time_pretransfer:  0,082169s
      time_redirect:  0,000000s
 time_starttransfer:  0,186839s
                    ----------
         time_total:  0,343926s
```

So it takes a little bit under 200ms for the first byte to arrive from the server. The remaining 143ms is to transfer all the bytes to me.

After I have run that a couple of times my worst result is

```
    time_namelookup:  0,043707s
       time_connect:  0,053465s
    time_appconnect:  0,093538s
   time_pretransfer:  0,093793s
      time_redirect:  0,000000s
 time_starttransfer:  0,194928s
                    ----------
         time_total:  0,516847s
```

So the first byte is still arriving under 200ms, the remaining time is network transfer.

I have also tested this Q/A [Get MIME type from filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension) because based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1313399) it is expected it has a large size due to the length of the question and/or answers. In fact that page is 483K. That is roughly 1,5 times more bytes.

Its timing is:

```
    time_namelookup:  0,036470s
       time_connect:  0,068119s
    time_appconnect:  0,108068s
   time_pretransfer:  0,108327s
      time_redirect:  0,000000s
 time_starttransfer:  0,219468s
                    ----------
         time_total:  0,666037s
```

The time to first byte goes a bit up, just over 200ms now, network transfer time takes up most of the time, as expected. The server processing time doesn't increase even linear with size so that shows there is plenty of headroom.

Given that we are looking at extreme cases and that the server side timings look pretty decent I don't think lazy loading is worth spending time on now, given its complexity and the small gain that is expected. If network latency is indeed troublesome you can fallback to the mobile view of the site. For now that reduces the payload a lot.

You can also visit: http://teststackoverflow.com/ as that collects performance data. Now and then you'll get a page rendered that contains an Ajax call to load that specific site, exactly to obtain client-side performance data. That data is used to make decisions on caching, optimizations, sizing etc.

Worth reading: [Stack Overflow: The Architecture - 2016 Edition](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/)

Comment: But you are not on [3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G)(?).